# Prevent Parent From Overflowing Child

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements:

- First, a green background.
- Above lies a blue box (covering a portion of that green background).
- My yellow and last element should now lie above the blue box, but below my green background WITHOUT being blue's child (due to other styling).

How would I achieve that with HTML and CSS?
Here two example pictures:

[image]

[image: example1]

code example:

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.first {
    background-color:green;

    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.second,.third {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
}

.second {
    background-color:blue;
    top: 40px;
    left: 200px
}

.third {
    background-color:yellow;
    top: 140px;
    left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

The yellow box should overflow the blue one, but *not* the green one (as in pic. 1). At the same time it shouldn't be blue's child (reason: I have skew() on it, skew-ing back to normal on the child, makes its content blury. I have also tried to use ::before for the skew() which led to other issues, thus yellow should not be a child of blue).

Here an example video:

- the green box doesn't move
- the blue box moves to the left on scroll
- the yellow box moves up on scroll

The issue, is that the yellow box overflows the green one. It should *only* overflow the blue one, and hide behind the green one. I cannot have yellow as a child of blue, since I have skew() on it, which (even when skew-ing back) causes blury and deformed text.

https://streamable.com/r3v409

Comment: Post your code in your question please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 sure, here u go:)

Comment: Your image examples are contradicting each other. Is the yellow box meant to show only while it's over the top of blue? Or is it meant to also show when it's overlapping neither green or blue (eg. bottom right of your boundary)?

Comment: @Kyle ty for telling me. Yes I made a mistake. If the yellow box is neither on/below green or blue, it should be visible. I will edit the image shortly

Comment: Are you creating an [Escher drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_(M._C._Escher))?  I doubt this is feasible because of the layering paradox you describe. It might help if you'd explain your overall goal better.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the second diagram like this.

The main points to note here are that the green box is being represented by 2 pseudo elements that each have a different z-index.

And the only way I was able to get this to work was to rotate 2 of the boxes using **transform**, while making sure that the green box was **not** using transform, otherwise it would then cause the overlap/underlap to fail.

```css
    body{
        padding: 100px;
    }
    div{
        position: absolute;
        width: 260px;
        height: 40px;
    }


    .green::before,
    .green::after{
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        background: green;
    }
    .green::before{
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .green::after{
        z-index: 0;
    }


    .green{
        top: 180px;
    }
    .yellow{
        transform: rotate(300deg);
        background: yellow;
    }
    .blue{
        transform: rotate(60deg);
        background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="yellow">
    Not a child of blue
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, I have uploaded an example video of what I am trying to achieve. I should have been more clear about my problem, as I am not able to cut my element the way you did (due to scrolling animations, the cut would need to be moved etc.)

Comment: @Covy In your video, are you just trying to have the yellow overlap the green? Are you able to share your code from the video?